# Get month wise YTD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the data in the table like below.

```
Company  period      sales
-------------------------
a        2018-01-01   21
a        2018-02-01   22
a        2018-03-01   23
b        2018-01-01   24 
b        2018-02-01   25
b        2018-03-01   26
```

My desired output looks like below:

```
comp  year month  YTD values                      MTD values
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a     2018 jan   <sum of sales in jan 2018>      <sum of sales in jan 2018>
a     2018 feb   <sum of sales in jan+feb 2018>  <sum of sales in feb 2018>
```

and so on for further months.

I have tried with the below query :

```
SELECT Company
    ,month(period)
    ,sum(sales) AS MTD
FROM tablea
WHERE datediff(year, period, getdate()) = 0
GROUP BY month(period)
    ,company
ORDER BY company
    ,month(period)
```

Here I am getting the value for `mtd` correct but I also want to include a new column `YTD` which gives `cumulative sum or running total`. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using `SQL Server` or `SQLite` ?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation *and* window functions:

```
select
    company,
    year(period) yr,
    month(period) mn,
    sum(sales) mtd,
    sum(sum(sales)) over(partition by company, year(period) order by month(period)) ytd
from tablea
group by 
    company,
    year(period),
    month(period)
order by 
    company,
    year(period),
    month(period)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9044ab7b759d2bf21a0c79790fa58356)**:

```
company |   yr | mn | mtd | ytd
:------ | ---: | -: | --: | --:
a       | 2018 |  1 |  21 |  21
a       | 2018 |  2 |  22 |  43
a       | 2018 |  3 |  23 |  66
b       | 2018 |  1 |  24 |  24
b       | 2018 |  2 |  25 |  49
b       | 2018 |  3 |  26 |  75
```